# Plotting a specific function in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$x(t)$,xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-2,ymax=2,grid=major,grid style={solid}]
\addplot[bojagrafa,line width=1pt,smooth] expression{(sin(90*x))+0.5};
\addplot[domain=-5:5,blue,samples=125,line width=1pt] expression{sin(90*x)+0.4*rand};
\addplot[bojagrafa,line width=1pt, smooth]expression{(sin(90*x))-0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is graph function: `x(t) = sin(90t) + 0.4·rand` and `y(t) = sin(90t)±0.5`
But i can not make it right like one below on picture, anyone help :(

[image: This graph]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You almost done. You only need add this code to your document, which in preamble has code line `\usepackage{pgfplots` ..., so what is the problem?

Comment: I actualy added pgfplots package but my graph need to be exact copy of this one on picture.Mine have different middle plot :(

Comment: Re-Welcome...Please can you put a minimal complete compilable code starting from \documentclass to \end{document} with the packages that you use? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**
I reduce samples number to your 125.

Let me noted, that exact copy of showed image is against of random function (seed of function is not defined, so it can differ from compiling to compiling)). So, if you really like to have exact copy, you need scan original image and include it in your document as graphic file and to image add note about source of image (This would be honest).

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-5,    xmax=5, xlabel=$t$, 
    ymin=-2,    ymax=2, ylabel=$x(t)$,
    grid=major, 
%
    domain=-5:5,
    samples=125,
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1pt}    
            ]
\addplot [red]  expression{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\addplot [blue] expression{sin(90*x)+0.4*rand};
\addplot [red]  expression{sin(90*x)-0.5};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
I would show illustration of a noisy sinusoidal with noise limits on the following way:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    grid,
    minor y tick num=4,
    minor x tick num=2,
    xtick = {-1.5*pi,-pi,...,1.5*pi},
    tick style = {font=\small},
    xticklabels={$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,0,
                            $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$},
    xmin=-1.5*pi,   xmax=1.5*pi,    xlabel=$t$, 
    ymin=-2,        ymax=2,         ylabel=$\sin(t)+ 0.4{\cdot}X(t)$,
%
    domain=-1.5*pi:1.5*pi,
    samples=301,
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick, line join=round},    
            ]
\addplot [red]  expression{-sin(x)+0.4};
\addplot [blue] expression{-sin(x)+0.4*rand};
\addplot [red]  expression{-sin(x)-0.4};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that is not it.I think problem is in samples

Comment: @WeLazt, sorry, your comment as question is not enterally  clear.  Ma answer reproduce showed  image. Please (again), explain what is your problem!

Comment: Okay so I need to created same graph like one on image.I already created it but it needs to be exact copy.Mine have different blue plot than one on picture but it needs to be exactly same.I hope I did explained it 

Comment: @WeLazt, if you have problem with colors, thickness of lines and similar, than please reformulate your question accordingly. Also will help, if  you will extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much I researched and found out that you are right. +1

Answer (score 1):

You asked this some days ago and deleted you question before I could post my answer. Anyway this his how I would have done it:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm,margin=4cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi, ymax=2,
        , samples=100, grid=major,
        xlabel=$t$, 
        ylabel=$x(t)$,
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        ymin=-2,ymax=2,
        xtick = {-4,...,4}, 
        ytick = {-4,...,4}
        ]
        
        \addplot[red](\x, {sin(\x r)-0.5});
        \addplot[red](\x, {sin(\x r)+0.5});
        %\addplot[only marks,blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] (\x, {sin(\x r)+0.5*rand});
        \addplot[blue] (\x, {sin(\x r)+0.49*rand});
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]